# How to run Python Selenium script on Android device?

Tags: android, python, selenium

I have working Python script using Selenium (Windows), and I want run same script (with driver replacement) on android device. I found some info about Selendroid and Appium, but they seem to be used for connecting to Android devices, not to port code.

I'd be glad for help with this issue or some useful links to read about it.

Answer (score 1):

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) Is the way do the thing which you want.

Kivy is the library which provides the platform to execute python, also kivy is open source so anyone can use that.

[Github Link](https://github.com/kivy/kivy)
[Kivy Showcase link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.showcase)

Comment: Thx, I'll try it. I forgot to mention that I've already use Pydroid to port general code and the problem is in Selenium drivers. But may be this will work.